# Make Excel ribbon less gigantic

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, ribbon

The ribbon in Excel (from Office Professional Plus 2016) is GIGANTIC.

Compare the vertical size in the two images below:

[image]

[image]

The top screenshot is from changing the ribbon setting to "Show Tabs" and then clicking on a tab such as `Home`, while the bottom is "Show Tabs and Commands", but that's not all it does. It makes the thing huge vertically.

I understand there are some slight differences with what is shown on the two, but I'd like to always show the ribbon, but at the more reasonable size of the "Show Tabs" setting, like the top picture. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

4th icon from the very upper-left corner allows you to select additional commands to add to the quick command bar up there.

One of these options is **Touch/Mouse Mode**. Click this to add the button to the bar.

Now click this new button (it looks like a hand with a pointing finger) and change it to **Mouse**.

I'm not sure how you switched, but it looks as though you went into Touch Mode, which spaces the buttons on the ribbon further apart so they are more finger-friendly. Switching back should shrink the bar back.

Comment: Upper-left. Sorry. Corrected.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea that was there. Maybe it was an installation default that set it to Touch Mode. In any case, one click changes it across all Office products. I wish I could upvote answer 1000x. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's usually there by default on any touch-screen systems, and it's quite handy there. I'd wonder if there's an unknown keyboard shortcut that might have been struck accidentally, or there's always just the odd chance it was an odd misconfigure at the get-go. Either way, I'm happy I was able to help.

Answer (score -1):

It's not immediately obvious, but to the far right of my toolbar I have a small indicator pointing upwards - [image: Indicator position above help text]

Clicking this hides the bar, and everything on it - so I never use it.

To get it back you need to click on the main toolbar name at the top left of the screen.

I use autohotkey to change my mouse middle button click to (CTRL+f1) to show and hide instead.

Comment: I want to show the ribbon all the time, just with the smaller view. Currently, I only get that view if I have it set to "Show Tabs" and then click on a tab such as `Home`.

Comment: Showing or hiding the tabs or commands isn't what OP is looking for.